# Repository for source install?

Tags: ubuntu, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the source ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) I could install Diamondback (1.4.6) on Ubuntu 9.10, Karmic Koala. However I am not sure which repository to use ? Would it be advisable to use Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) or Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick) source lists ?

Any help is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9936/repository-for-source-install-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are doing a source based installation you do not need to add anything to your sources.list files.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you are referring to the ubuntu sources.list files.
In that case definitely not! Ubuntu 9.10 should run on 9.10 sources.

The best method is probably to upgrade to 10.04 for getting 10.04 sources.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-07-17**:
@dornhedge: Yep ! .... I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - so that should be no hassle until 2013 - when Canonical stops supporting Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.